# StringTokenizer doesn't show the 0 at the end of a number

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

i'm working with Java ,i'm using a StringTokenizer in order to have a part of my String but the problem is when  i'm using "StringTokenizer" a part of my result doesn't appear  this is my java code :

```
for(String iopp:opp){
                   StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(iopp,"form:blocConfigurations:configurations:0:parametrage:options:");
                   while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
                   ind.add(tokenizer.nextToken());

                   }
               }   

               logger.info("Mes indices sont :"+ind);
```

and in my console :

```
   what was it :[form:blocConfigurations:configurations:0:parametrage:options:1,            form:blocConfigurations:configurations:0:parametrage:options:6, form:blocConfigurations:configurations:0:parametrage:options:9, form:blocConfigurations:configurations:0:parametrage:options:17, form:blocConfigurations:configurations:0:parametrage:options:20, form:blocConfigurations:configurations:0:parametrage:options:21, form:blocConfigurations:configurations:0:parametrage:options:22]
   17:13:45,876 INFO  [com.sfr.price.functionalTest.scenario.impl.AJLINGE.etapeParametrerOption](821) [] Mes indices sont :[1, 6, 9, 17, 2, 21, 22]
```

StringToknizer works exacltly but i don't understand why in this element
             form:blocConfigurations:configurations:0:parametrage:options:20
       it shows me only 2 and not 20

thanks in advance

Comment: As per comment in source,  StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for * compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is * recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the <tt>split</tt>
 * method of <tt>String</tt> or the java.util.regex package instead

Answer (score 8):

Read javadoc: [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).
Every character in `form:blocConfigurations:configurations:0:parametrage:options:` is delimeter. `0` is also delimeter as this string contains `0`.
`StringTokenizer` is not right tool for this task. You can try with `String.split`:

```
String[] tokens = iopp.split("form:blocConfigurations:configurations:0:parametrage:options:");
```

But be careful because `split` takes regex as delimeneter. And if you have some special characters in your delimeter string, you need escape it.

Comment: when i use split it returned something like this :
Mes indices sont :
[] Mes indices sont :1
[] Mes indices sont :
[] Mes indices sont :6
[] Mes indices sont :
[] Mes indices sont :9
[] Mes indices sont :
[] Mes indices sont :17
[] Mes indices sont :
[] Mes indices sont :20
[] Mes indices sont :
[] Mes indices sont :21
[] Mes indices sont :
[] Mes indices sont :22

Comment: @asmae you can remove all empty strings from array

Answer (score 0):

Every character of delim in [new StringTokenizer(str,delim)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)  is treated as separate delimiter.

You should consider to use [String.indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)